# Modern Home Page

Tags: modern-pages

Can someone help me where to find the modern homepage layout? When I create a new site page it always has a banner which I can't remove. I'm looking for the site page that doesn't have the fixed banner like the default homepage.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The modern sitepage content type has the banner by default.
You can remove it by creating a new site page using the user interface.
Then click edit (top right)
Then in the banner/title box click the X icon below the image icon in the top left of the section. This will remove the banner image but leave the title in place.

Hope this helps

[image]